# getting 2 value from 2d array by position

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, arrays

i need to get 2 value from this array order by position

```
var sosmed = [
  "Twitter",
  "Facebook"
][
  "rey",
  "ray lard"
];
```

how i can get value like this `"twitter = rey" , "Facebook = rey lard"` or

- Twitter = rey
- Facebook = rey lard

Comment: php or javascript?

Comment: javascript. ill use it inside <ul><li></ul></li>

Answer (score 0):

I used splat(...) operator to transpose array and then converted it into key values pair of each sub array

```
$arr = [
    [
        "Twitter",
        "Facebook",
    ], [
        "rey",
        "ray lard",
    ],
];
$arr = array_map(function($item){ return [$item[0] => $item[1]];},array_map(null, ...$arr));
echo json_encode($arr);
```

[Working demo](https://3v4l.org/NVg2N)

Javascript version,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var temp = [
    [
        "Twitter",
        "Facebook",
    ], [
        "rey",
        "ray lard",
    ],
];
temp = temp[0].map((col, i) => temp.map(row => row[i]));
result = [];

for(i in temp){
    if(!result[i]){
        result[i] = [];
    }
    result[i][temp[i][0]] = temp[i][1];
}
console.log(result);
</script>
```

**Output**

```
[{"Twitter":"rey"},{"Facebook":"ray lard"}]
```

Comment: not yet :( need more solution, output should be not an array

Answer (score 0):

For a 2D array like this

```
var array = [[
  "Twitter",
  "Facebook"
],[
  "rey",
  "ray lard"
]];
```

Solution: In VanillaJS

```
let obj = {};
array[0].forEach((item,index) => {
obj[item] = array[1][index] || '';
})
```

Using Lodash:

```
_.zipObject(array[0], array[1]);
```

Output:

```
{Twitter: "rey", Facebook: "ray lard"}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your array declaration. First fix that.

```
var sosmed = [[
  "Twitter",
  "Facebook"
],[
  "rey",
  "ray lard"
]];
```

After that, you can get the desired result by performing a `map` operation on your first sub-array inside the main array and creating appropriate object for each of them.

```
const result = sosmed[0].map((company, i) => {
  const obj = new Object();
  obj[company] = sosmed[1][i];
  return obj;
});
```